# Complex analysis about Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let g(t) be any continuous function on the boundary T of Disk D(0,1) centered at 0 and radius 1.
Then, extend g(t) to the interior of the disc by $g(z) = \int_T g(t)/(t-z) dt $
If it is well defined, my question is:
(1), is g(z) continuous on the whole closed disk.
(2, can g(z) always be able to extended a little bit to a bigger open disk so that g(z) is holomorphic on that disk.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an extended comment, since it's not a definitive answer to either questions.

Notice that expanding in a power series we have
$$
\int_T \dfrac{g(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\, d\zeta= \int_T \sum_{k=0}^\infty \zeta^{-1}\left( \dfrac{z}{\zeta}\right)^k g(\zeta) \, d\zeta= \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k \int_T \zeta^{-k-1}g(\zeta)\, d\zeta,
$$
where the change of sum an integral is justified by the uniform convergence of the series on compact subsets of $|z|<1$. Now parametrize $T$ counterclockwise by $\zeta=e^{2\pi i t}$, with $0\leq t\leq 1$ (so that $d\zeta/\zeta= 2\pi i dt$) to write
$$
\int_T \dfrac{g(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\, d\zeta = 2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k \int_0^1 e^{-2\pi ikt}g(t)\, dt= 2\pi i\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k \hat{g}(k),
$$
where we have abused notation a little and identified $g(e^{2\pi it})$ and $g(t)$, and $\hat{g}(k)$ denotes the $k$-th Fourier coefficient of $g$.

If you write $z=re^{2\pi i \theta}$, then the above reads
$$
\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_T\dfrac{g(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}\, d\zeta = \sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k e^{2\pi i k\theta}\hat{g}(k).
$$
So as $r\to 1^-$, we see that the limit should be the function $\tilde{g}$, built from $g$ by deleting all the negative Fourier coefficients. You can get several types of convergence here (as $r\to 1^-$): We have convergence in $L^2$, nontangential convergence (meaning approaching boundary points along cones inside the disk).

However I'm not sure at the moment if you can even conclude that the limit function $\tilde{g}$ needs to be continuous (if you want to look more into this, look up Hardy spaces of the unit disk), so as of now I don't have a definite answer to (1) or (2) beyond pointing out what the limit *is*.

On the plus side (at least for (1)), I'd imagine that a Littlewood-Paley characterization of Hölder continuous functions should allow you to conclude in the affirmative for (1), when $g$ is in this class.

Added: A negative answer to (2) can be given as follows. Consider the function $g$ whose Fourier coefficients are given by
$$
\hat{g}(k)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{k^2} & k>0,\\
0 & k\leq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Such a $g$ is continuous, owing to the fact that it's Fourier series is absolutely convergent. On the other hand, we know that its extension to the unit disk is given by
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^2}z^k= \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k z^k,
$$
so that its radius of convergence of this power series is 1 (since $\limsup |a_k|^{1/k}=1$).

Comment: I am new to Complex analysis. This Fourier series argument really open my mind.
So, as long as the negative part of Fourier series is 0, then the extension in (1) is continuous.
For (2), i think your example works. If the function can be extended into a slightly bigger open ball, then we will be able to write the the function in the whole open ball as a power series, whose coeffcient must fit a_k. Thus, by the radius argument, it can not be extended. Thanks a lot!